# Ajax Call to Wordpress Function Returns Empty Array

Tags: php, wordpress

The following function returns empty string. Can somebody suggest what is wrong in the code below? I am making an AJAX call to this function.

```
function LoadImagesForMenus() {

    $filenameArray = [];
    $validextensions = ["gif", "jpg", "jpeg", "png"];
    $handle = opendir(get_template_directory().'/analyzer-images/');

    while ($file = readdir($handle)) {
        if ($file !== '.' && $file !== '..' && !empty($file)) {
            $filenameArray[] = $file;
            $ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if (in_array($ext, $validextensions)) {
                $fileArray = [];
                $fileArray["fileName"] = "http://xn--ernhrungsberaterzrich-71b08c.ch/wp-content/themes/abundance/analyzer-images/$file";
                list($width, $height) = getimagesize("/home/httpd/vhosts/xn--ernhrungsberaterzrich-71b08c.ch/httpdocs/wp-content/themes/abundance/analyzer-images/$file");
                $fileArray["width"] = $width;
                $fileArray["height"] = $height;
                if ($width !== null && $height !== null) {
                    array_push($filenameArray, $fileArray);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($filenameArray);
    exit(0);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried to debug it? Have you confirmed that the file exists, that your paths are correct, that the file is successfully being read, that $filenameArray has the correct values before returning etc?

Comment: The files do exist in the folder. Wordpress did not log any errors in the code above. Moving statement echo json_encode($filenameArray); within while loop returns array with image information.

Comment: So the problem is that the array is getting cleared somehow, is that right?Where in the while loop was the array printing - is it before or after the `if($width !== null && $height !== null)`?

Comment: I tried inside the if condition and it worked as well as after it. It worked both ways. The echo statement has to be inside while loop.

Comment: I don't see anything in your code that could clear the array. Thats everything from your ajax file?

Comment: Yes. It is. Thanks for looking into the problem.

Comment: I've just thought of something - something must be causing the script to die, and its not getting to the end to print it out. So maybe your code is reading (or trying to read) in a file that it can't handle for some reason. I suggest testing it with just one image in your `/analyzer-images/` folder that you know for sure works, to see if its a particular file thats causing it to die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to json_encode() is failing. You should check for an error on calls to json_encode.

```
$json = json_encode( $filenameArray );
if ( $json !== FALSE ) {
    echo $json;
} else {
    error_log( 'json_encode() failed with error=' . json_last_error() );
}
```

There is probably another entry which json_encode() cannot handle. You should either skip this entry or set the options to json_encode() to handle the characters in the entry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solved my problem. I really appreciate.

Comment: The first time I had this problem it took me a very long time to solve - the disadvantage is the examples in the PHP manual pages doesn't show the error check.

Comment: This was freaking me out. I have been searching over it since yesterday. Can't thank you enough for your valuable reply.